# What is purpose of end hinge on garage door?

Tags: hinges, garage-door

What is purpose of end hinges that is mounted on 4 section garage doors? This one is from a Pella garage door and mounts on side above where the rollers are mounted. The door uses 6 of these. -3 on each side of the door. [image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't it apparent that it does what *any* hinge does?

Answer (score 7):

They connect the sections together so the entire door moves when opening or closing it.

3 on each side means each except the bottom one is connected to the one below.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, Pella likes to do things the hard way.  Normally that whole assembly is one standard part: the hinge and the roller holder all in one piece.

What Pella's setup does, however, is allow the hinge pivot point to be *inside* the door.  That is why you see a chamfer/relief on the top edge of the door section, to keep the door segments from pinching.

The standard part has the hinge point about 3/8" this side "above" the door's interior surface.

[image]

The other hole is for the roller, note that each row of hinges puts the roller farther away from the door, since the roller track is at a slight slant.

Comment: I assume you couldn’t  use what you was talking about on this door . Unless I misplaced it,  I am missing the three left edge hinges. I can get hinge like you show locally but would have to order one like I showed.

Comment: Probably not, the holes don't look look like they line up.